# How to send keystrokes from unicode string in golang

Tags: go

I need to output unicode string as keyboard input on Windows, Linux and MacOs platforms. String could have none-ASCII printable chars from different languages (latin, cyrillic etc.). Platform specific system API calls should be used in each platform. 
For Windows I've found SendInput function. Unicode char could be passed to this function to create keyboard event.
Are there any analogs for Linux and MacOS?

I've found  [keybd_event](https://github.com/micmonay/keybd_event) package for golang for simulating keystrokes. It works well with ASCII chars by using virtual codes. But It haven't support none-ASCII chars.

Comment: Resource requests like this are off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: Having said that, I'm not sure if this is even theoretically possible. Many (perhaps most) Unicode "characters" are composite, and would require complex, multi-stroke keyboard input to generate from the keyboard. And the exact method of input depends on many things (not just the OS). In Linux, for example, it also depends on whether you're at the console, or in X, and if you're in X, it depends on which Window manager/DE you're using, and how it's configured.

Comment: @Flimzy, I think asking for the Linux and Mac equivalents for the SendInput API doesn't qualify as a resource request.

Comment: @Peter: It seems like the epitome of a resource request for me. What else would be the answer, if not some resource?

Comment: @Flimzy, one or more code snippets showing how to use analogous Linux/Mac APIs in Go, ideally pointing out differences and caveats. And yes, as usual an answer should also include links to the documentation for those APIs, but it does not need to be exclusively that.

Comment: This is an impossibly complex question; entering non-ASCII characters on a us-en keyboard layout requires multiple keystrokes and/or chords on every OS. In other keyboard layouts, some non-ASCII characters may be more readily accessible, but it will vary by keyboard layout *and* by operating system. The scope of this problem is huge - effectively the space of the desired character map, multiplied by the number of keyboard layouts to support, multiplied by the number of OSes to support.